# Copy directory - Working out progress

Tags: java, android, backup

I have a routine which i've been using for a while to copy a directory from an SD card to a plugged in USB drive. It works, but as there can be 3000 photos, i'm sure you get that it an get a bit slow. So i'm trying to implement some sort of update progress bar.

Here is my code that does the copying;

```
public void copyDirectory(File sourceLocation , File targetLocation)
            throws IOException {

        Log.e("Backup", "Starting backup");
        if (sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
            if (!targetLocation.exists() && !targetLocation.mkdirs()) {


                throw new IOException("Cannot create dir " + targetLocation.getAbsolutePath());

            }

            String[] children = sourceLocation.list();
            for (int i=0; i<children.length; i++) {
                copyDirectory(new File(sourceLocation, children[i]),

                        new File(targetLocation, children[i]));

            }
        } else {

            Log.e("Backup", "Creating backup directory");
            File directory = targetLocation.getParentFile();
            if (directory != null && !directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
                throw new IOException("Cannot create dir " + directory.getAbsolutePath());
            }

            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(sourceLocation);
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetLocation);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
            in.close();
            out.close();
            Log.e("Backup", "Finished");

        }

    }
```

I assume that I need to check how big the directory is before starting so i've added:

```
    public static int CountFilesInDirectory(String location) {
        File f = new File(location);
        int count = 0;
        for (File file : f.listFiles()) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                        count++;
                }
        }

        return count; 

}
```

But I guess, I can't work out how to put A and B together. I can't work out how to increment in the right place for the update. - I could be on the completely wrong path! Any tips really would be appreciated.

Comment: are you copying subdirectories too ?

Comment: Yeah all sub directories. It's essentially a working backup

Comment: probably need to count files in subdirs as well (recurse countFilesInDirectory call if (file.isDir())

Answer (score 0):

http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/05/android-asynctask-example/

see the above link async task loading concept will help you

Comment: Hi - i've actually got it currently running in an async task in the background and updating the notification area before and after backup. But that's what i want to add the progress bar to. Hence trying to work out the current steps

Comment: No worries :-) I appreciate the input

Comment: tell me while counting the photos it needs to show percentage in progress bar ?

Comment: Yeah, essentially it's to give the user who's backing up an indication that it's actually still working. Waiting 40mins whilst it just says running isn't really good enough